# When can a windowed cosine be considered band-limited signal?

Tags: window-functions, bandpass, bandwidth, window, cosine

I have an exam in the following days and i have no clue of what is the response to this question in the exam:

> given this signal:
>
> $$g(t) = H\left(t+\frac{T}{3}\right) f(t) - H\left(t-\frac{2T}{3}\right)f(t)$$ $H(t)=$ Heaviside step function
>
> $f(t) = \cos(\omega_1 t)$
>
> Define a value of $T$ for which the signal $g(t)$ can be considered
>   band limited.

This question doesn't make much sense to me. This is a windowed cosine function and it's bandwith depends on the value of $T$, it's always limited! 
Unless $T$ approches 0 and it can be seen as an impulse. Am I missing something?

Comment: They're talking about *band*-limited, not time-limited. This is about the spectrum of $g(t)$.

Comment: Sure, i know that it's about the fourier spectrum, my problem is that g(w) (the transform of g(t)) it's always band limited, being it's fourier transform a simple translated sinc, which is always limited

Comment: Why is a sinc function in the frequency domain band-limited?

Comment: I don't think the question can be answered without a proper definition of "can be considered band limited". What's that supposed to mean ?

Comment: Well the value of sinc decreases when we increase the frequency, so there will be always a value of T such that |g(w)|<-60dB

Comment: The envelope of the sinc function decreases for any $T>0$, so that cannot be what the question is about.

Comment: Well that's my problem, sometimes in this type of exercise the prof make us define the sampling frequency Fs necessary to sample properly the signal, could it be that he consider the signal band-unlimited if the fourier transform of the signal |g(w)| doesn't go below -60dB before the Nyquist Frequency?

Comment: @DarioFormi That looks like a question for your professor, not for us...

Comment: My answer would be $T=0$, which makes $g(t)=0$, which _is_ bandlimited.

Comment: @MBaz I thought i was missing something. Thanks to anyone that responded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T=0 or T=infinity.

Any non-zero signal with finite length support in one domain has infinite support in the other domain.

cos(wt) is only theoretically band-limited if infinite in length.